# Is it possible to provider a "support" contact/group in Telegram ? (Either a write-only group or with a bot)

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I hope my question is compatible with the rules of Stackoverflow, I will try to make it as precise and specific as I can.

The aim is to use Telegram as a "support" contact for users of a platform to contact the support team. But all "solutions" I can think of does not suit the aim, for example :

- If I create a group for this purpose, all users will receive all support requests from other users, they will be "spammed".
- I I give them my private number, I will receive the messages but not the rest of the support team

Is there a way to create a "write only group" for some users, they could write in the group, support team could read the group but not the other users ?

Another way I was thinking of was using a bot : People would contact the support bot, that would forward the question to the support group (group with only the support team), and someone from the team would contact the user with private message ?

And I think channels are not suitable either to my aim.

Sorry for this "how to" question, but I spent a lot of time searching forums, stackoverflow, but I found nothing close to my aim.

Thanks a lot in advance for any hint or advice,

Denis

Comment: That's what you need https://core.telegram.org/bots

Comment: You can save messages from bots on separate database and support team could read the messages but not the other users